# Как обратиться к объекту через C# скрипт Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть объект "objBall" - это asset, просто готовый круг. И этот объект должен появляться случайно в разных местах канваса, а игрок должен успеть кликнуть по нему. Сам алгоритм прост, язык C# знаю, по крайней мере - основы, а вот с Unity впервые. И ещё вопрос, скрипт можно прилепить на главную камеру сцены для удобства? Или же надо для отдельного объекта новый скрипт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Скрипт лучше прикрепит на отдельный объект, например "BallSpawner" или "GameManager". Хотя вариант с камерой будет работать.
2. Что бы сослаться на объект из скрипта есть довольно много способов. Для вашего случая идеальным будет создать поле класса:

   ```
   [SerializeField] //не public, но видно в inspectore
   GameObject BallPrefab;
   ```

Теперь в инспекторе можно на поле BallPrefab перетащить игровой объект (лучше [prefab](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html))

3. Теперь spawn объектов, его можно реализовать так:

   ```
    var positionForInstaniate = //здесь генерим случайную позицию
    Instantiate(BallPrefab, positionForInstaniate, Quaternion.identity);
   ```

Для определения времени spawn удобно использовать таймеры или [корутины](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html)

4. И останется обрабатывать клики игрока. Здесь можно обратится к [OnMouseDown()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html)

PS: для образца можно посмотреть мою домашнюю работу: [GitHub.Asteroids](https://github.com/ssa112112/Asteroids) , там все несколько сложнее, но если начать с AsteroidsSpawner.cs вполне можно распутать клубок того, что происходит.